# How to get todays data using SQL query in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below table(Record_details) in my database.

```
ID NUMBER,
PATH VARCHAR2(100),
Date TIMESTAMP(6);
```

Here, I have written below query to get records from this table

```
SELECT * FROM Record_details
```

my questin is: I need to fetch all the data for todays's date;

```
SELECT * FROM RECORD_details where Date = '?';
```

I have tried googling but could not find exact working query
https://popsql.com/learn-sql/sql-server/how-to-query-date-and-time-in-sql-server
https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-commands-to-check-current-date-and-time-timestamp-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly didn't create table whose column name is `date`; it is reserved for datatype name.

Anyway: you could

```
SELECT * FROM RECORD_details where trunc(date_column) = trunc(sysdate);
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM RECORD_details where date_column >= trunc(sysdate) 
                               and date_column <  trunc(sysdate) + 1
```

---

Pick the one you find more appropriate. The 1st option won't use index on `date_column` (unless you create a function-based index), while the 2nd will (but - the 1st one looks simpler and *prettier*).

---

What do these values represent?

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate, trunc(sysdate), trunc(sysdate + 1) from dual;

SYSDATE             TRUNC(SYSDATE)      TRUNC(SYSDATE+1)
------------------- ------------------- -------------------
06.04.2023 08:00:29 06.04.2023 00:00:00 07.04.2023 00:00:00

SQL>
```

- `trunc(sysdate)` returns today's date set to midnight
- `trunc(sysdate) + 1` returns tomorrow, set to midnight

Therefore, if `date_column` is larger or equal to today's midnight and less than tomorrow's midnight, that's exactly what you want: today's values.